# How to find Rth (Thevenin Equivalent R) of this circuit

Tags: circuit-analysis, thevenin

[image]

Suppose I find \$V_{th}\$ = 2 V. How to find \$R_{th}\$ seen from a,b?

My effort is short ab, and then in this case, 2//4 = 4/3. Note here that, the line across \$R_L\$ is a node (short ab). So the total current is

16/(5+4/3*2) = 2.087 A.
So I get Isc = 2.087 A. Note that \$I_{sc}\$ is the current flowing into the node when I short ab.

So \$R_{th}\$ = 2/2.087 \$\Omega\$.

Am I correct?

Comment: Vth is ok, but you've got the wrong value for Isc. Isc current is not equal to 16/(5+4/3*2) because Isc is just a part of this total current. Do the KCL.

Comment: Just to add to G36's comment, in addition to removing the load from the terminals in order to find the Thevenin voltage it's also then often convenient to simply place a \$1\:\text{A}\$ source across those same terminals in order to find out the response voltage there. Assuming you used KCL, as suggested, then that's easy to do and re-solve. Now, knowing the voltage change and the current makes it really easy to find the Thevenin resistance.

Comment: This is a bridge (with or without R1 in the circuit); in either case a delta-wye transformation will help. With R1 removed, your Rth is wrong.

Comment: Thanks! let me do it again

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Thévenin resistance can be determined using the extra-element theorem or [EET](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extra_element_theorem) forged by Dr. Middlebrook. It is a really easy and cool way to determine transfer functions in circuits where a particular element is bothering you. To determine a resistance (or an impedance), install a test generator \$I_T\$ across the output terminals. This is the excitation or stimulus. This current source will generate a response \$V_T\$  across its terminals. What we want is \$R_{th}=\frac{V_T}{I_T}\$

[image]

According to the EET principle, the element causing troubles here would be \$R_5\$ but you could choose any other resistance of course. We have the choice to set to infinity (open-circuit it) or replace it by a short circuit.  So the selection depends on how you visualize the circuit when the extra element is replaced by a short circuit or open-circuited. We go for the second choice and determine the resistance \$R_{ref}\$ offered from the output terminals (across which \$R_{th}\$ must be determined) after setting the 16-V bias source to 0 V (a short circuit). The value is simple to obtain by inspecting the circuit: no equation here.

Then, suppress the excitation \$I_T\$ and determine the resistance \$R_d\$ “seen” from \$R_5\$’s connecting terminals. Again, no stress, it is a simple series-parallel combination obtained by inspecting the circuit.

Finally, null the output response \$V_T\$ to determine \$R_n\$. This is a degenerate case and you replace the current source by a short circuit to “see” the resistance \$R_n\$  from \$R_5\$’s connecting terminals. Same philosophy as in the above, inspect the circuit.

This is it, the final result is obtained by assembling the pieces as follows: \$R_{th}=R_{ref}\frac{1+\frac{R_5}{R_n}}{1+\frac{R_5}{R_d}}\$. The below Mathcad file shows the exact formula and a resistance computed to \$2.875 \Omega\$.

[image]

You can see how easy it is to apply the EET which is part of the fast analytical techniques ([FACTs](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1119236371)) toolkit. You divide the circuit into small pieces that you individually solve and assemble at the end. If later on you find a mistake, no need to restart from scratch, just fix the guilty drawing and voilà. I added in the Mathcad sheet the EET formula for which \$R_5\$ is now considered infinite rather than a short circuit as initially selected. The \$R_{th}\$ expression slightly differs but results are identical.

I have added a quick SPICE simulation using a .TF primitive which instructs the simulator to run a transfer function at the output node while the modulation comes from the 16-V input source. It confirms the small-signal output resistance \$R_{th}\$ obtained using the FACTs.

Not only you did not write a line of algebra (with the risk of making mistakes) but you obtained a nice-looking *low-entropy* expression in which you have series and parallel arrangements. It is invaluable to see how the final result changes if one element changes to a small or large value. If you use KVL or KCL, it is very likely that you obtain an arm-long expression with all mixed-up labels providing no insight of what does what in the formula. To that respect, FACTs are difficult to beat.